# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection error while inserting data

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net

I am getting error

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

I tried different method by changing the code. I have even checked the mysql.err file but still unable to identify why I am getting this type of error and whether this error is from MySql engine side or from .net side.

I am using mysql 5.7 community version and .net

[image]

Comment: Code is text, please post it as formatted text, Not Pictures. That way people can use it in answers of maybe even test an answer without haviing to recode

Comment: You remove something from a list by an index number that is larger than the items in the list, hence the error. But posting an error message is of no use. You need to post the code that is throwing the error.